# How do i apply conditional formatting for background colour in Powerbi based on date column updating by IF Statement

Tags: powerbi

The custom column created:

```
Date Test = SWITCH( True(), AND ( ISBLANK(oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish]), ISBLANK(oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Start]) ), (oData_Activity_Dimension[Schedule_Finish]), Isblank (oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish]), (oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Start]), IF((oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish]), (oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish]),(oData_Activity_Dimension[Schedule_Finish]) ))
```

this is pulling dates into a single column, based on if certain dates are populated. i need to apply colour coding to this. so that if actual start is entered ="yellow", actual finished entered = "green", schedule finish (no actual/schedule start) = "grey", and if the schedule finish goes over todays date = "red".

this doesnt seem to be something i can do with the conditional format - background colour options provided in PowerBI. can someone please provide a way to apply this to the column?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's an error in the IF, you haven't stated a logical test:

```
IF(
    (oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish]), 
    (oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish]),
    (oData_Activity_Dimension[Schedule_Finish]) 
)
```

When you've fixed that just have it output numbers rather than times. For instance have the double blank output 1, black finish as 2, etc.

Then under formatting you can set up a rule based on the measure and format the colors there.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. can you point out the issue with the IF? i have it so that if there is a actual finish, display actual finish, other wise display schedule finish - is there something here i am missing? thank you ... for the second point - i need to be able to display the dates that are in those fields mentioned, each has a diff date(wither scheduled or actual date) based on the conditions mentioned above. if i enter numbers, i can apply colour coding based on which number is outputed using conditional format, this makes sense and thank you for providing this guidance.(see p2)

Comment: however, do you have any idea how i can keep my date fields for display, while also applying the colour coding/numbering for colour coding? thank you so much for your help, much appreciated. Kevin

Comment: The IF doesn't check if the statement is true or false, you've just put in the finish time, you need to check it against something. Just use the same SWITH function give it a name like 'Formating xxx' and have it output the integer and format based on that.